# Rails controller returning JSON response with Content-Type=text/html

Tags: ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails 4 app has a page that submits a form with params remote='true' and format='json'.  The response is initiated by this helper method:

```
  def respond_to_update(rec, values={}, redirect_path=rec)
    respond_to do |format|
      if rec.update values
        flash_notice rec
        format.html { redirect_to redirect_path }
        format.json { render action: :show }
      else
        respond_to_error rec, :edit
      end
    end
  end
```

The code for the controller#show action is

```
  def show
  end
```

However, the XHR response has contradictory values:

```
xhr.responseJSON
Object {id: 1, created_at: "2014-06-08T20:28:48.720Z", updated_at: "2014-06-08T20:28:48.720Z", content_type_id: 7, bio_asset_id: 2}

xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')
"text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

In other words, it returns a JSON object while at the same time Content-Type header is 'text/html'.  My Javascript code gets the response but I suspect that this may cause other problems, and I didn't notice this before.

Where in Rails does the Content-Type header get set?